# How to handle Lucene's "System.UnauthorizedAccessException - segments.gen" in an Azure WebApp?

Tags: azure, lucene, umbraco

Umbraco 7.1.8 running as an Azure web app has yo'yo'ed a couple of times, the logs show the following error message:

```
ClassName": "System.UnauthorizedAccessException",
"Message": "Access to the path 'D:\\home\\site\\wwwroot\\App_Data\\TEMP\\ExamineIndexes\\Internal\\Index\\segments.gen' is denied.
```

There is a very large stack trace I won't paste just yet, however it's starting with

```
at Lucene.Net.Store.SimpleFSDirectory.OpenInput(String name, Int32 bufferSize)   
at Lucene.Net.Store.FSDirectory.OpenInput(String name)
```

No one has accessed any of the site files directly during the crashes FYI, nor has anything other than Umbraco content edit based changes / cache updates been made (though maybe they are key to the issue?)

Question is, is this a lock of some kind created by the website (umbraco e.g. during a publish / cache update) or is this something systematic with Azure / Web Apps / Server Setup / IIS that could cause segments.gen to lock / access denied? It's strange that it worked after a while with no intervention.

Any insight appreciated, if not to simply help work out the issue by deduction.

Comment: If its an Azure web App then this is probably not a permissions issue. Have you tried re-indexing?

Comment: DId you ever find any resolution?

Comment: Not a satisfactory answer, however there were issues with the cloud service that was causing odd performance issues. It appears another resource on the same server we were on was using large amounts of resources and I guess potentially causing errors. In the end Azure moved the cloud service to another physical server for us, but it was a lot of hassle :-p